# How to manipulate precise element of an array with redux

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-redux

Today,I tried to make a list with redux where you can add and remove elements as you want [visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eNrk.png). My list is in fact an array updated every time user click on "Add to the list" or "Remove last added element".

Now I try to do one thing but I don't know how to do it. Indeed I what I wanted to do is, if for example the user try to add Tristan again, the FromControl with Tristan became 'sucess' (I use bootstrap too) but I don't know how to reach this element precisely, because if I used a variable in my reducer and i said the style of my FromControl depends of the state of this variable, every FormControl will become 'sucess'.

Thanks in advance for your help :) 
(Sorry for my english level too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the element in your array and work your way up from there.

I see as well that you have a lot of warnings in the console, I suggest you to add the `key` in your components when inside a foreach and move the `setState` calls to `componentWillMount` or another appropriate place.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer and for you help for my multiple warning :P. I don't understand one thing. When I get my component with the Array.prototype.findIndex() how did I change his style ?

Comment: Since you are using redux you can bind the store to the params of your component and use this to render your component differently. If you didn't already I suggest you to have a look at [this tutorial](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html) that makes a example that could help you understand better.